# How to store session into disk in java

Tags: java, spring, session, tomcat

I have a web application, using JVM as session storage. But recently when a certain number of users exceed. The application goes down. So what I am trying to do is transmit the session to files using Tomcat Persistent Manager Implementation which stores session in files with extension `.session` and that ended up with no where. Solved several `NotSerializableException` errors and starts getting `DestructionCallbackBindingListener` error along with several other errors. So fixing all these errors is not practical as my application is huge one. Also Tomcat isn't noted for which attribute is cannot serialize in a class.

As long as the session is in  RAM (JVM heap space), that's not a problem. But if the app server decides to swap it out to a more durable medium. Then it starts getting errors unpredictable times. So somebody please suggest a way for the session storage out of JVM other than i mentioned if exists and please explain how.

Comment: Are you running a single Tomcat or a cluster ? Maybe is it time to run a cluster but you would face the same problems if you add non serializable objects to your user sessions. I believe it should be easy to check what you're adding to these sessions.

Comment: Running single tomcat. Without serializing no any option is there? In my case it is not easy to check whats adding to these session. Because i will get notserializableexception for classes and that classes contains hundreds of attributes. In the error log it would not show which attribute couldn't serialize

Comment: _Without serializing no any option is there?_ I think, no solution, but other people will comment maybe. You are short in memory, but how much memory do you have ? If you are storing too much data in the user session, why do you need to store all that in the session ? Having faced such problems, it sounds like a poor design/implementation. At one moment the technical debt must be taken in account, and solved. Good luck.